# ValidationError: 1 validation error for StructuredTool

Tags: python, openai-api, pydantic, langchain

I was getting an error when trying to use a Pydantic schema as an `args_schema` parameter value on a `@tool` decorator, following the [DeepLearning.AI course](https://learn.deeplearning.ai/functions-tools-agents-langchain/lesson/6/tools-and-routing).

My code was:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class SearchInput(BaseModel):
    query: str = Field(description="Thing to search for")

@tool(args_schema=SearchInput)
def search(query: str) -> str:
    """Searches for weather online"""
    return "21c"
```

And was getting this error:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for StructuredTool
args_schema subclass of BaseModel expected (type=type_error.subclass; expected_class=BaseModel)
```

Comment: Langchain offers migration guide. Basically they suggest to keep using pydantic v1 or v2, but not both. Then when langchain migrates to pydantic v2 internally, all users of pydantic v1 can migrate once using migration tool.
https://python.langchain.com/docs/guides/pydantic_compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Downgrading to pydantic `1.10.10`** worked for me.

Add `pydantic==1.10.10` to your `requirements.txt` and install it with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

or with the command `pip install pydantic==1.10.10`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Using `pydantic.v1` will works.

Change the line below

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
```

to

```py
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, Field
```